# Energy-Momentum tensor in Classical Mechanics

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I can compute Energy-momentum tensor in classical field theory using Noether's theorem and translation invariance of action, but I think I can't exactly calculate how to calculate same thing in classical mechanics , say for $$L = \frac{1}{2}mv^2 - \frac{kq^2}{r}$$
where for simplicity we can assume particle is trapped in $xy$ plane.

Specifically I am confusing meaning of indices $\mu, \nu$ not being clear since in classical mechanics $\mu, \nu$ are only time (Lagrangian is not Lagrangian density) and I think what I ended up with is only Energy term. (I know for above system momentum is not conserved but I can't get momentum term even if it is conserved):

$$\delta L = \frac{d}{dt} \left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}\delta x + \frac{\partial L}{\partial y}\delta y\right)$$

For the field theory case it is possible to write
$$\delta L = \partial_{\mu}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial_{\mu}\phi)}\partial_{\nu}\phi\right)\epsilon^{\nu} \tag{1}$$

and also think of dependence of L on coordinatates $x^{\mu}$:
$$\delta L = \epsilon^{\nu}\partial_{\nu}L = \partial_{\mu}(\delta^{\mu}_{\nu}\epsilon^{\nu}L) \tag{2}$$

To get quantity $$\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial_{\mu}\phi)}\partial_{\nu}\phi\right) - \delta^{\mu}_{\nu}L \tag{3}$$
be conserved tensor.

The analogous approach doesn't work since in continuous case $\phi$ and $x$ (or any generalized coordinate) are the same thing and change of lagrangian wrt field and position do not yield a new equation as it did in $(1)$ and $(2)$ where $\delta L$ was interpreted in 2 different ways.

So is my conclusion correct that in CM, we only have energy conservation law from translation invariance of Lagrangian but no momentum part?

Comment: 'I can compute Energy-momentum tensor in classical field theory' How exactly do you compute the em tensor? From a nonrelativistic field lagrangian? Give a reference.

Comment: eq $(3)$ is em tensor

Comment: If you apply it to a lagrangian .

Comment: see eq (9) and (12) at [link](https://www.physics.umd.edu/courses/Phys624/agashe/F10/solutions/HW1.pdf)

Comment: It would be helpful to extend your question by making this explicit. Only now I see that you are talking about the electromagnetic lagrangian.

Comment: A nonrelativistic particle lagrangian where the mass term is left out is a poor starting point for a discussion of energy-momentum. You should at least use the relativistic one, $-m\gamma^{-1}$

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first things first. In the usual treatment, the indices $\mu \nu$ belong to ${0,1,2,3}$ and include both time and space parts. It is true that it is conventional to use Greek and Latin indices respectively to denote time and space components, however, it is clear from the context of the equation when this is so. There is nothing un-classical about field theory. Classical mechanics is completely generalized to the case of the continuum, where the usual mechanical quantities pass from the discreet to the continuous, see Goldstein chapter 13 for many examples of completely classical field theories. So it is the case that you mean to say that you wish to understand the analogies between the discreet and continuous treatments, and not that between the classical and field theoretic.
Let us calculate $\delta L$:
$$\delta L={\partial L\over \partial x}\delta x +{\partial L\over\partial y}\delta y+{\partial L\over\partial\dot x}{d\over dt}\delta x+{\partial L\over\partial\dot y}{d\over dt}\delta\dot y.$$
We know from the Euler-Lagrange equations that:${d\over dt}\big({\partial L\over\partial\dot q}\big )-{\partial L\over \partial q}=0$, hence:
$$\delta L={d\over dt}\bigg ({\partial L\over \partial\dot x}\delta x+{\partial L\over \partial\dot y}\delta y\bigg ).$$Of course the canonical momentum is given by $p=\partial L/\partial\dot q$. So, as you say, conservation of momentum follows from the translational symmetry of the Lagrangian, however, the discreet analog of the field momentum is clearly there, it just looks different because of the way the field transformation simplifies when the field is just $"q"$ as opposed to $\phi$. Nothing different occurs in either case.

Comment: I got your point about field theory still being classical just continuous version of what i called classical, but there is still something not carrying in the analogy I think : If you look at eq $(1)$ and $(2)$ from there $(3)$ is derivable, where since 1 and 2 are same their difference satisfies conserved current condition. analog conservation condition I think I didn't include in the discrete case, by which I mean we have only defined $\delta L$ but no more equations relating it (it is more of a definition). I wanna ask, can we say $\delta L = 0$ (a new relation) analog to current condition

Comment: Also, in field theory case some information about energy also can be found , e.g $T^{\mu \nu}$ for $L = \frac{-1}{4}F^{\mu \nu}F_{\mu \nu}$ has $T^{00}$ as energy density, but conservation of momentum didn't include energy information. Yes, Hamiltonian is conserved and this is deducible but it wasn't arrived directly from translation invariance, so maybe this is another way analogy didn't exactly carry over (I know this is additional question, maybe ask this seperately )

Comment: The fact is that one always says that $\delta L=0$ in the case that the Lagrangian is invariant under the given transformation, which your example, it was; i.e. the Lagrangian was subject to a contact transformation. However, when you derive $\delta L$ for field theory version, you are not subjecting the Lagrangian to a simple contact transformation, hence transformation of coords. is not a strict symmetry and one is able to a derive non-trivial eq.(2).

Comment: Check out the Wikipedia article on Noether's theorem, there you will see the discreet version and field theory version compared. I think there you will be able to see what you are looking for.  You are right in that there are difference apparent between the two, however, the fundamentals are completely the same. In this sense, the calculations are analogous, e.g. one can do field theory calculations for transforms that are strict symmetries and eq.(2) will be trivial there too.

Comment: When doing Newtonian point mechanics in the 4-vector formulation, all of the temporal parts are trivial and so they mostly filter out, excepting the case where electromagnetic effects are considered; here the Lorentz symmetric nature of the field equations provide the rich temporal-spatial form seen in field theoretic treatments of Noether's theorem.